# How to get my own local IP using scapy?

Tags: python, ip, scapy

I couldn't find a way to find my local IP address using ONLY `scapy` (and not the Python's stdlib). 
The only workaround I found is sending a dummy package and using it to retrieve the address from the source field, but I don't feel like it is a good solution.

Comment: This question is about Scapy, not Python standard library, and there is, in Scapy, a specific way to do what the OP wants.

Comment: (and by the way that's an interesting question)

Comment: from my understanding from [here](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html), the way to do it with scapy seems to be: `IP().src`. Altough this creates a dummy packet, the dummy packet is not sent.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a look at https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/routing.html#get-local-ip-ip-of-an-interface
you can get the local IP of any of your interfaces using

```
>>> ip = get_if_addr(conf.iface)  # default interface
>>> ip = get_if_addr("eth0")
>>> ip
'10.0.0.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick reminder: you might have more then one IP address. There's one for each interface you have. To get the IP address for scapy's current working interface you should do `get_if_addr(conf.iface)` as suggested by Cukic0d in his comment.

Here's a way that will work in both windows and linux. This will get you the ip address for all your interfaces.

**Working in scapy shell**

```
>>> s = set() # there will be redundencies so we'll use set to remove them
>>> for line in read_routes():
...:     s.add(line[4])
...:
>>> s
{'10.0.0.4',
 '169.254.106.110',
 '169.254.17.51',
 '169.254.177.137',
 '192.168.56.1',
 '192.168.99.1'}
```

**In python shell**

```
>>> import scapy.all as S
>>> s = set() # there will be redundencies so we'll use set to remove them
>>> for line in S.read_routes():
...:     s.add(line[4])
...:
>>> s
{'10.0.0.4',
 '169.254.106.110',
 '169.254.17.51',
 '169.254.177.137',
 '192.168.56.1',
 '192.168.99.1'}
```